# How to set menu items to the left side of actionbar?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

I am making an android application which has an actionbar and the actionbar contains the menu items on both sides. So, I need to add one menu item at left side and one menu item at right side of the actionbar.

For this i have created a custom layout and set it to the action bar. As shown in the below image

[image: action bar having custom layout]

but i just want to have menu items at the places of left side and right the other screenshot shows the action bar with menu items

[image: actionbar with menu itemss]

In this the actionbar contains the menu items. So, i just want the put the plus button menu item to the left as same the first screen shot but i dont want to use the custom layout for this,

Also i need to chnage the font style of the actionbar title and put it in center.

Please help me. I spent many hours on this.

Thank You

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I've spent several days trying to achieve exactly this.

Answer (score 7):

You can directly add navigation drawable to your toolbar try this code :

```
yourToolbar.setNavigationIcon("Resource id")

yourToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new ClickListener(){})
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom view for that. You can't use the options menu inflation for your use case.

Set the style of the activity to Theme.AppCompat and don't use NoActionBar in the activity or the application style.

Create a custom_menu layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/add"
                 android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                 android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                 android:scaleType="centerInside"
                 android:id="@+id/action_add"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView android:text="NewsFeed"
                 android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="centerInside"
                 android:id="@+id/text_appname"
                 android:textSize="30sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:textColor="#FFF"
                 android:paddingTop="5dp"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/action_add"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/search"
                 android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                 android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                 android:scaleType="centerInside"
                 android:id="@+id/action_search"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity onCreate add the following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainfeed);
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_menu, null);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(customView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    ImageButton addContent = (ImageButton)    customView.findViewById(R.id.action_add);
    addContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // ...
        }
    });

    ImageButton search = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.action_search);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```